# What is causing a 'no password supplied' error on my attempt to create a User model and corresponding table?

Tags: flask

So I'm attempting to create a "User" model in this test implementation of a Flask app. The URI information says that the password is optional,so why am I getting a password error when running this?

```
#Create "User" model and users table
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql://testuser@localhost:5432/example'

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False)

db.create_all()
```

It's supposed to run the server and the User model should also be initialized as a table in the db, but I just get the "no password supplied" error.

Answer (score 0):

It is a short answer: you didn't supply the database password in the `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI`

Comment: Password is optional correct? In the tutorial that I was doing it was mentioned that password isn't necessarily needed

Comment: It depends on how you setup your database. Can you connect to the postgresql db with `testuser` only?